# How to preserve color information in .x3d import in cycles render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, color

I have a bunch of protein surfaces that I selectively color with Chimera and then export as an `.x3d` file. I then import this file into blender. In the material view, with blender render selected, I can see the colors. However, when I switch over to cycles render, the colors disappear. Is there any way for me to save the colors as a texture map and then load them into cycles again?

[The .x3d file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qzdaw94v8yvxeuf/brfTest.x3d?dl=0)

[The .blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e7hpvpkfoeocur4/brfTest.blend?dl=0)

**EDIT:**
Note that Chimera is a protein structure viewing program, but that just gives the context of my question. In essence, I would like to know how blender and its renderers deal with data imported from `.x3d` files.